# java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype

Tags: rest, maven, spring-boot, jetty

I am newbie in spring mvc, jetty and restful.
I'm trying to deploy my restful App is running perfectly when using this command >

```
mvn clean jetty:run
```

It gives following error:

> **java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log:
>   Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype**
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail (ServiceLoader.java:239)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300 (ServiceLoader.java:185)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService (ServiceLoader.java:376)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next (ServiceLoader.java:404)
>       at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next (ServiceLoader.java:480)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory. (LogFactory.java:77)
>       at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory. (LogFactory.java:65)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer. (WsWebSocketContainer.java:92)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer. (WsServerContainer.java:85)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init (WsSci.java:131)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup (WsSci.java:47)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup
>   (ContainerInitializer.java:140)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart
>   (ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:347)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1497)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp (JettyWebAppContext.java:360)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1459)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:852)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:278)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:545)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart (JettyWebAppContext.java:428)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:418)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty (AbstractJettyMojo.java:477)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute (AbstractJettyMojo.java:343)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:169)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
>   (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)

my pom.xml as follows : [pom.xml](https://github.com/adminfieldService/my_mpom/blob/master/pom.xml)

my project as follows: [project](https://github.com/adminfieldService/OpenFireRestService)

I have tried it many times but I've been unsuccessful. Please help!

Answer (score 5):

Since you are running the app using Jetty, this error tells you that you have conflict with tomcat and I believe you have spring-boot-starter-web dependency in your pom and tomcat is embded by default which causes the conflict with jetty. Simply exclude it like below. It works for me

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

`org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer`

If you are using `jetty:run` then the above class is not allowed to be in your classpath/classloader.

Find which dependency brings it in and remove/exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved just now .
follow this direction :
your repository -> jetty -> apache-jsp
delete whole folder
now run
problem solved :)